# Problems creating a matrix with mahout math class

Tags: java, matrix, mahout

i'm creating a matrix 3x4 with Math MAhout class DoubleMatrix2d, i wrote something like this to begin:

```
package org.apache.mahout.math.matrix.impl;

import org.apache.mahout.math.function.BinaryFunction;
public class creaMatrice extends DenseDoubleMatrix2D {

    public static void main(String args[]){

    double array[][]= { {1,2}, {4,8}, {5,0}, {4,5}, {2,9}, {1,5}, {9,0}, {2,6} };
    //creo una nuova matrice vuota
    DoubleMatrix2D matrice;
    matrice = new DenseDoubleMatrix2D(3,4);//creo una 3x4
    matrice = matrice.assign(double array[][]);
    int prova = matrice.getQuick(2,3);
    System.out.println(prova);

  }
}
```

im getting errors about compile, but the first thing i need to know is if is the right way to do that :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is better to ask these questions on the mahout user mailing list.  Otherwise, you take the risk of nobody who knows about Mahout ever seeing your question.

In general, the DoubleMatrix2D is deprecated in Mahout and you should use Matrix instead.  Some code still uses the old stuff, but as we test the old Colt code, we are converting it
to the new form and using the new data types.

Comment: Ok Ted, i tried but without success, seems that my problem is still unsolved. Right now i'm running seqdirectory and seq2sparse from mahout without success, this is what i obtains: AVVERTENZA: Unable to add class: org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.RunLogistic and so on....can you help me please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could you please state what your goal is here? 
This little example doesn't really do anything which couldn't be done with a nested loop on the base array.

As for the compiling errors, it would be helpful to see the console output.

Comment: Hi Jules, thanks. Well my goal is to create a matrix to use SVD decomposer and test it with mahout. When i try to compile with maven, i obtain: mahout/math/creaMatrice.java:[8,7] <identifier> expected and 3 same errors.